# how to retrieve date format data from database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

How to retrieve date format data from database to textbox.my code attached here

```
SqlDataReader sdr=sda.ExecuteReader() if (sda.Read()==True)
Txtdateofbirth=sdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
```

but time also showing in text box..how to get date only in text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to change your query that you are firing on your database. Select the right format that you need.

You can try this .. `convert(varchar(20),getdate(),101)`This will return in `mm/dd/yyyy`

```
102 - yyyy.mm.dd
103 - dd/mm/yyyy
104 - dd.mm.yyyy
105 - dd-mm-yyyy
```

etc.

Use `Replace(convert(varchar(11),getdate(),106), ' ','/')` for `DD/Mon/YYYY` format.

Comment: @UnniR .. use `Replace(convert(varchar(11),getdate(),106), ' ','/')`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the date only as a string by using ToString() with a custom format.

eg.

```
DayDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").
```

Comment: If you are performing a DB operation then it is advised to get the right format of data from DB itself if possible. Doing data manipulation at BL level adds another computation which is not suggested. However if DB fails or not supports then in such cases we can do computation at BL level.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that you can approach this:

Doing it in the database layer at the time you do query (preferred):

Example (works with MS SQL Server)

```
SELECT Id, Name, DateOfBrith, CONVERT(datetime, DateOfBirth, 101)
FROM Person
```

I am not sure what database engine you are using, check the documentation for that version.

If you wanted to do this in your code/business layer (BL) then you could do this:

```
SqlDataReader sdr=sda.ExecuteReader(); 
if (sda.Read()==True)
{
    Txtdateofbirth=sdr.GetValue(2).ToString();
    DateTime dateObject;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(Txtdateofbirth, out dateObject) == false)
    {
        //Did not recieve date value back, do something
    }
    var displayDate = dateObject.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: Use whatever format you want, here is the MSDN page for DateTime custom formating: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx